# How to compress image converted to a Bitmap , using glide

Tags: java, android, bitmap, retrofit2, android-glide

I am implementing an android app ( in java) in which am sending images taken with the camera , that will be sent over the internet through Apis . The problem is , it takes some more few seconds to be loaded on the backend side  and i want the process to be faster . So i want  to convert images into Bitmap and compress it using Glide . How can i figure it out it ? How can i take the image from the external storage using Glide . Here 's what i've done

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(creanceDetteList.get(i).getEncodedImagePath());
                //Convert bitmap to byteArray
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
                //Then convert to base64
                String encodedImage= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Why would you load an image file in a bitmap and then compress the bitmap to an image file back? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: `and compress it using Glide . ` ? You cannot use Glide to compress a bitmap.

Comment: There is nothing in your code using Glide.

Comment: @blackapps i want to compress the bitmap using glide and i don t know how to do it

Comment: Can you read? Repeat: `You cannot use Glide to compress a bitmap.`.